# build_filters() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_bad_filters'

Tags: django, tastypie

I just updated my code from django 1.8 to 1.11 and so i also had to update tasty pie. Before update everything worked fine but now I am getting this error on one of my tests.
Here is the test case

```
def test_does_not_return_restricted_fields_when_insufficient_permissions(self):
    self.user.user_permissions.all().delete()

    response = self.api_client.get(url,
                               format='json',
                               authentication=self.create_apikey(username=self.username, api_key=self.api_key),
                               data=data)
```

Here is the full Trace,

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/spare/local/projects/towerportal/apps/exchangedb/tests/test_api.py", line 68, in test_does_not_return_restricted_fields_when_insufficient_permissions
        response = self.get_response(self.detail_url)
      File "/spare/local/projects/towerportal/apps/exchangedb/tests/test_api.py", line 26, in get_response
        data=data)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/test.py", line 70, in get
        return self.client.get(uri, **kwargs)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 536, in get
        **extra)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 340, in get
        return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 416, in generic
        return self.request(**r)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 501, in request
        six.reraise(*exc_info)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
        response = self._get_response(request)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 185, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 221, in wrapper
        response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 470, in dispatch_detail
        return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 493, in dispatch
        response = method(request, **kwargs)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1376, in get_detail
        obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=basic_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1195, in cached_obj_get
        cached_bundle = self.obj_get(bundle=bundle, **kwargs)
      File "/spare/local/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 2176, in obj_get
        applicable_filters = self.build_filters(filters=kwargs, ignore_bad_filters=True)
    TypeError: build_filters() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_bad_filters'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could your please paste your tastypie resource code?

Without related code, I can only guess that it is because you override 
`def build_filters():` in your modelresource class, but the newer version of tastypie added a `ignore_bad_filter` parameter in the function definition which you do not have in your modelresource code.

The `build_filters` function declaration in the latest tastypie:
`def build_filters(self, filters=None, ignore_bad_filters=False):`

The old version probably does not have the `ignore_bad_filter` parameter. To fix this, just add `ignore_bad_filters=False`key word parameter to the `build_filters` function in your modelresource class.

Comment: It is also generally good practice to collect and pass *args and **kwargs to the superclass, if you are calling it.  This adds a bit of future-proofing:  def build_filters(self, filter=None, *args, **kwargs):  super().build_filters(filter, *args, **kwargs).  Even if you aren't calling the superclass's build_filters, capturing **kwargs will prevent exceptions from trivial changes to method signatures.

Comment: Also, the tastypie docs fail to mention this new parameter; it'll be fixed in the next point release.